# Is there any resource to learn interiors of a house for particular classes in 17th Century in Bohemia?

Tags: social-history, 17th-century, everyday-life, resource

I would like to learn details of the living places for particular classes and professions in Bohemia in 17th Century. (For example a burgher, or carpenter guild master etc.)

I try some novels written in those times.

What are the canonical resources in this field?

Comment: what countries, what part of the 17th century, what continent, what social class?

Comment: I was wondering a broad resource mainly for all Europe. But in particular, Bohemian kingdom, Germany and Austria during Thitry Years war, burghers, guild masters, wealthy people (not necessarily noble people)

Comment: those three countries (one of which was a mashup of dozens of small states in the 1650's) had a vastly different architectural and economical models at that time. you should center yourself on one of them, say, Asutrian metropolitan areas ( wien, for example).

Comment: CptEric, I will narrow my question's context then. Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 3):

**Buildings and structures**

panoramic of prague in the late 17th

[image]
<sub>(source: [old-prague.com](http://www.old-prague.com/historicke/31.jpg))</sub>

[image]

**Workshops**

the only one i've been able to find is the misseroni workshop, in the 1630's, it was a stonecutrting and glasswork workshop. Their house is still there, but i don't know if it's the same.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You could also research the 17th-century weapon workshops of Adam Brand, Paul Ignatius Poser, the Neireiter family and Leopold Becher.

probably also notable to look into this article:

> History of Guilds and Crafts in the Český Krumlov Region, Bohemia

[The article in question](http://www.encyklopedie.ckrumlov.cz/docs/en/region_histor_cechy.xml)

There seems to be a lot of information in there, and by looking at google docs there seems to be many [interesting sources on glassmaking in bohemia during that time and similar crafts](https://books.google.es/books?id=3bViBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&dq=bohemian%20workshops%201600&hl=es&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=bohemian%20workshops%201600&f=false)

Comment: Thanks @CptEric It is a good start for me to how to go deeper.

Comment: glad to be of help!